# Restful URL After Insert

Tags: ajax, rest

I am new to RESTful URLs and I have a general question. Let's say I have a URL that I use to retrieve student records: `somesite.com/students/123` which retrieves the details for the student with ID 123.

I then do the following to load an empty form for adding students: `somesite.com/students/0` where zero indicates that I want to display an empty student detail form (or `somesite.com/students/new`).

The question I have is that after I add a student record I get back a new Id. However, if I add the record using AJAX without submitting and refreshing the page, my URL still shows `somesite.com/students/0`. If a user clicks refresh then the empty form is displayed again rather than the new student record.

How should that be handled?

Answer (score 0):

It's not like your server can't respond to AJAX requests, right?
All you need to do is send back the newly generated ID, and then:

1. Use `window.location = 'new_url'` to redirect the user
2. Or even better, use `history.pushState()` (if available) to change the URL without any redirection (and reloading) happening at all

One thing that seems off, though, is the use of `GET page/students/0` to get an "empty record", or, as I understand it, a "template" for new records. I don't think that's how RESTful services work, but then again, I'm not an expert in REST services.